# Understanding JavaScript responses

Tags: javascript, response

I am using the following PHP code to respond to a JavaScript `fetch()` request.

```
$json = json_encode(array(
    'status' => 200,
    'resources' => $dataObj
));

http_response_code(200);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $json;
exit;
```

Back in my JavaScript code, after I get the response, I can do the following:

```
console.log(response.status);
console.log(response.resources);
console.log(JSON.stringify(response.resources));
```

The first line works and shows a value of `200`. The other lines display `undefined`.

Now, if I add response.json() before my code, all three console lines show correctly.

```
let resp = await response.json();
console.log(resp.status);
console.log(resp.resources);
console.log(JSON.stringify(resp.resources));
```

My question is: Why in the first example can I correctly see the status of 200, but I need to use the json() function in order to see the data object?

Comment: Because that's how it works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: You're mixing up the `status` code which comes back from all http requests with the `status` property you manually add to your json response.

Comment: @Jamiec Oh no, you are correct. That is exactly what I was doing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make an http request - any http request - you will get back a status code. This is available on the response object.

You have also sent a `status` property as part of your response body, and until you explicitly tell your code to read the response body as json (`response.json()`) you wont be able to read *any* of your custom response.

So, basically, the status you can read is the one sent back by the server - not the one on your json.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment under my question made everything clear. I did not realize there were two 'status' properties at play here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) you will always get an object back which you don't need to parse. It's already an object literal, specifically a [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response](http://Response%20instance).

This object has a property called `status` which returns 200 in your first case.

If you do however call the method `json()` on this object, it will parse the **body** of your response, not the whole thing. In this body you have **your status from the backend** not the status of the `Response`.

That's why `let resp = await response.json()` will return you your actual response data with your `resources` and such.

Answer (score 0):

the response is actuallay a string:

```
  "{'status':200,'resources':'sth'}"
```

and that string hasnt a *resources* property. You first need to parse it to an object literal.

To clear up some confusion:

The server sends a full response, so the upper is just the *body* , while a http response also consists of a *header*. If you do:

```
response.status
```

thats actually the headers status.

Comment: That's not the reason. In this case `obj.status` would return an error. beacuse as you said, it's just a string...

Comment: @lexith no thats not the jsons .status but the headers status info

Comment: i think we are miscommunicating ;) The response is not a string. It's a response object, that's why `response.status` works but his `resources` are actually in the body of the response object which need to be parsed first with `response.json()`